# Extract specific value in pandas dataframe based on column condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am faced with a small problem, the solution of which is certainly very simple, but I cannot find how to do it.
Let's say I have the following pandas dataframe `df`:

```
import pandas as pd
X = [0.78, 0.82, 1.03, 1.06, 1.21]
Y = [0.0, 0.2521, 0.4905, 0.5003, 1.0]
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':X, 'Y':Y})
df
    X       Y
0   0.78    0.0000
1   0.82    0.2521
2   1.03    0.4905
3   1.06    0.5003
4   1.21    1.0000
```

I want to recover the value of `X` for which `Y` exceeds `0.5`; in other words, I am looking for a piece of program which creates a new variable `val` such as:

```
print (val)
1.06
```

I imagine only complicated things, style:

```
df['Z'] = df.apply(lambda row: 0 if row.Y <= 0.5 else 1, axis = 1)
df

    X       Y       Z
0   0.78    0.0000  0
1   0.82    0.2521  0
2   1.03    0.4905  0
3   1.06    0.5003  1
4   1.21    1.0000  1
```

But this shows me **where is** the `X` value I want (first appearance of `1` in `Z`), but it doesn't **extract** that value.

How could I do that in a simple way?

Comment: ```df.loc[df.Y.gt(0.5),"X"].head(1)``` ? I assume you are only interested in the value

Comment: what is your expect output?

Comment: @sammywemmy, this gives me the following output: `3    1.06`,  
`Name: X, dtype: float64`, not only the value `1.06` I expected.

Comment: You should be able to take it from there. ```df.loc[df.Y.gt(0.5),"X"].head(1).array[0]``` ?

Comment: Of course! This solves the problem, even if it means creating a small sub-file, which I thought I could avoid...

Answer (score 0):

We can check with `idxmax`, notice it will need have one value less than 0.5

```
df.loc[df.Y.gt(0.5).idxmax(),'Z']=1
df.Z.fillna(0,inplace=True)
df
      X       Y    Z
0  0.78  0.0000  0.0
1  0.82  0.2521  0.0
2  1.03  0.4905  0.0
3  1.06  0.5003  1.0
4  1.21  1.0000  0.0
```

If would like separated dataframe

```
df1=df.loc[df.Y.gt(0.5)]
```

Comment: actually, I have no interest in creating a new column `Z` (it is just a thought I had); so that the problem remains: how just creating a variable `val`containing the value `1.06` ...?